# How to Get Started with Gaussian Splatting

Tags: graphics, rendering, 3d-reconstruction

Gaussian splatting has gained [increasing popularity](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=12323590702419478298&as_sdt=5) for its efficiency and effectiveness in reconstruction tasks.

I possess basic college-level knowledge of mathematics, and I have basic knowledge in C++ and Python. Could anyone please advise where I should begin if I want to learn Gaussian splatting from scratch? What are the background knowledge required to understand/implement Gaussian splatting?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting from the [original paper](https://repo-sam.inria.fr/fungraph/3d-gaussian-splatting/) and its corresponding [project](https://github.com/graphdeco-inria/gaussian-splatting). The paper can provide you with in-depth knowledge of the entire Gaussian splatting workflow, including forward rendering and backward optimization.

One of the advantages of splatting over NeRF is its ease of implementation. Since the paper was published only half a year ago, there have been numerous implementations using various methods. Many of these implementations utilize rendering pipelines from different engines and platforms, making them quite user-friendly.

Here are some other useful implementations to get started with. You can choose one based on your familiarity with the tool or platform:

- [(WebGL) antimatter15/splat](https://github.com/antimatter15/splat)
- [(Three.js) mkkellogg/GaussianSplats3D](https://github.com/mkkellogg/GaussianSplats3D)
- [(Babylon.js) Babylon.js/gaussianSplatting.ts](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/master/packages/dev/core/src/Rendering/GaussianSplatting/gaussianSplatting.ts)
- [(WebGPU) cvlab-epfl/gaussian-splatting-web](https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/gaussian-splatting-web)
- [(Unity) aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting](https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting)

Comment: Thank you very much for those great resources :)